# ASP.NET input box not showing in browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to add input boxes in ASP.NET, but they are not showing up in the browser. I don't have any hidden properties and the only time they show is when I use set the display to block and give them a background color in CSS, but even then they are unclickable and can't be used.

Here is the markup:

```
<form action="" method="" class="p-4" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox id="tb1" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox rows="5" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Comment: That isn’t Aspnet mvc. It’s web forms

Comment: If you’re using this markup in an MVC project then you’ve simply mixed up frameworks.

Comment: hi, okay ignoring MVC part, I probably didn't understand what it means. It is a web form yes cause its for a website. What I would like to know is why it wont show on the browser at all. thanks

Comment: @FabianShamano: How specifically are you executing this application?  When you view the page source in your browser, what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with a webforms project, you are ONLY allowed ONE form tag in a given page.

So, when you create a new blank web page, then the default markup looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

So, in above you are NOT to mess with, nor change nor add MORE "form" tags in your markup. You are allowed one per page.

Hence, any and all markup you add to that fresh new created page?

It is to be placed inside of the existing form tag. The exception to this rule is if you are using a master + child page setup. In that case you will NOT HAVE any form tags in your markup.

So, now, let's add you markup you posted, but of course without the "form" tag you added.

So, we now have this:

```
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>

                <asp:TextBox ID="tb1" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox Rows="5" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
                <asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server"
                    
                    />


            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

And your "submit" setting for the OnClick of that button does not look correct.

In near all cases, you want to let Visual Studio create the event stub for you.

So, you can either double click on the button if you in "Design" mode, or if in "source" view, then you can type in the event stub, and hit ctrl-space.

This will prompt you for the event (button click) to be created in code behind for you.

Thus, the process looks like this:

[image]

Note VERY close in above, we also added an "id" to the button click event, and buttons and any server-side control (with runat="server") needs an "id" setting.

As noted, you can also while in the designer in most cases just double click on the button to create (and/or jump to the code stub behind). However, the button control (and near all controls) should have an "id" setting.

So, now when we hit f5 to run, then we see this:

[image]

In most cases, you should drag the text box, the button etc. from the tool box into the web form, as then "id" will be automatic assigned. However, in most cases one will of course change the automatic default id assigned to such controls to something better.

Comment: wow, thanks for all the effort to clearly explain what went wrong and how to fix it. This is really how answers should be given the the aim of giving solutions. I really appreciate you and wish other could follow your example :-)

Comment: Thank you kindly.  It's considered good forum manners to mark answers to your questions as accepted