Why don't I see the table after inserting it?
I am working with web forms, inserting a table with 12 rows and 6 columns but the table looks very small on one side and does not display in the entire container.



After testing, there is no problem on my side. Please describe your Visual Studio version in detail and the specific steps to reproduce the problem.

Check the source for table and td widths. You should set them.

I think it was just the view but I found the answer in the link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77815729/11278427
